# CSS: Empty inputs have a different line height to inputs with content?

Tags: input, css

This is not so much a specific problem for a certain site, just something that I seem to nortice in *every* project.

If you take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/U2TPK/). Click inside the input, the caret stretches to the height of the input. Now press a key, the caret shrinks to the text height. Does anyone:

a) Know why this happens

b) Know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not seeing this caret you speak of.  Is it browser-specific?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is, this is Firefox I am in. I mean the cursor, the flashing line? I don't know how else I can describe it.

Comment: This appears to be a Firefox (Webkit, maybe?) quirk. It doesn't happen in Internet Explorer 8 (Windows 7)

Comment: Huh, strange. It is a bit of a weird one. If you set the font-size of the input to 20 then the size remains the same throughout, but the text pokes out the bottom.

Comment: Happens only in Firefox for me

Comment: Well I suppose that settles it, it is basically a VERY small Firefox bug.

Comment: This does not happen in any of my browsers, including FireFox 3.5.2

Comment: @Wolfy87 It shrinks for 2px on both sides in Firefox. Wow, how did you notice that? :)

Comment: @Šime Vidas A keen eye I suppose, I like my sites to be pixel perfect, IE does not.

Comment: @Wolfy87 The issue is related to the height property being set on the INPUT element. You set it to 20px. If you remove that property, the issue also disappears.

Comment: Yes I know, I just looked into it, if you set padding like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/U2TPK/5/ then it is okay, but still, when you want a precicely sized input it is not good.

Comment: @Wolfy87 No, even with padding, the issue remains whenever the height is set. Try setting the height to 50px, and padding to 1px and you will see that you will have an over-sized caret at first.

Comment: "precicely sized input" total height = padding-top/bottom + line-height + border-size?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yeah I know. I just mean it is only because I am setting the height and is there a way around it. But I think atlavis is on the right track, just work out the height from all of the attributes added together and apply padding.

Comment: @atlavis I don't think so... I am not able to modify the height of the text-box by setting the line-height property. The height of the text-box is affected by setting the font-size property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's worth it, but if you insist on fixing this issue in Firefox, you could do this:

On the focus event, if the value of the text-box is an empty string, then:

1. set the value to `" "` (a space character)
2. move the caret to the beginning of the text-box

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U2TPK/11/

I am using a custom script to set the selection. It is located here: http://vidasp.net/js/selection.js
`selec.set(this, 0, 0)` will set the caret to the beginning of the text-box.

```
$("input:text").focus(function() {
    if ( this.value.length === 0 ) {
        this.value = " ";
        selec.set(this, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/U2TPK/12/
(this also handles the situation when the user repeatedly focuses the empty text-box)

Comment: Pretty good, well done. I may end up using this, it seems the only fix that allows you to set the height of the textbox and not get an over sized caret. I guess this awnsers section b of my question then.

Comment: @Wolfy87 Although, if you decide to use it, I recommend you to run the code only in Firefox. In Opera the caret positioning is late (which looks weird), and in Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), the above code doesn't seem to work - which is strange since it does work in this demo: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/select-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the problem is simple, the font-size inside the input is smaller than the actual input size so this should fix it, if you set the font to the desired size:

```
input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

or you could use:

```
input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting a fixed height for option fixed it for me.

```
option
{
    height: 12px;
}
```